# How to write comment in a jpeg image file that can be visible with image editor like irfanview etc

Tags: java, android, image

I want to write some comment , that can be visible with image editor like irfanview. I have tried to write comment on exif data , but its not showing on comment section. I think the way image editors allow us to comment on the image , are not saved into the exif data. Any idea how to do it.
Here is my code..

```
try {
    exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

    exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, geoInfoLAt);
    exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, geoInfoLon);
    exif.setAttribute("GPS Information", "Geo Information Lat-" + geoInfoLAt + " Long-" + geoInfoLon);
    exif.setAttribute("comment", "Geo Information: Lat-" + geoInfoLAt + " Long-" + geoInfoLon);
    exif.setAttribute("UserComment", "Geo Information: Lat-" + geoInfoLAt + " Long-" + geoInfoLon);
    exif.saveAttributes();

    Uri baseUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    ContentValues test_values = new ContentValues();
    test_values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, " Lat-" + geoInfoLAt + " Long-" + geoInfoLon);
    int res = getContentResolver().update(baseUri, test_values, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=?", new String[]{filePath});  // works fine!


} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Logger.showMessage("PictureActivity", e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

.. here UserComment is working and on exif tag it is showing , but i want to write information that can be visible with image editor software like irfanview.

Comment: `and on exif tag it is showing`. Where on which gui do you see it?

Comment: `// works fine!`. How do you check?

Comment: in the Irfanview image properties.

Comment: It is unclear which question your aswered. Please answer both questions.

Comment: i have checked the exif is not showing in the Irfanview image properties.

Comment: I want to insert the comment as hex value in the jpeg file so that i can read it by the following block...

Comment: while (ch != 0xDA && !(hasDims && hasComment)) {
             
                if (ch == 0xFE) {
                    // that's the comment marker
                    comment = new char[length - 2]; for (int foo = 0; foo < length - 2; foo++) comment[foo] = (char) in.read(); hasComment = true;} else {for (int foo = 0; foo < length - 2; foo++) {in.read(); } } }String comm = "";for (char chars : comment) { comm = comm + chars; }